# Write selectively to a range in spreadsheet not working with null values in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have used Spreadsheetv4. I have try to set null value (not update exist value) but it's not working.when we pass "" empty string it's working but it update empty value in sheet.

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken
   $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
   Google_Model::NULL_VALUE;
   $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
   $spreadsheetId = 'spredsheetid';
   $options = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');
   $values = [["1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
   $body   = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => $values]);    
   $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, "test- update todo!durationupdate", $body, $options);
```

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: Null is not supported.i got error "Invalid json payload" .
When i Pass "" empty string insted of null it's  working but it's add null value in sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Rigal my answer arrived a few time late...
You must not to use null or NULL, you must use Google_Model::NULL_VALUE

```
$values = [["1",Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE,Google_Model::NULL_VALUE]];
```

Or you can use a variable or whatever you want.
I hope this answer help someone. It was take to me some hours to find the answer.