# Skipping a value insertion on Google Sheets PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

```php
$valueRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();

// You need to specify the values you insert
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["$now", "SKIP", "SKIP", "SKIP", "$quantity", "SKIP", "SKIP"]]); // Add two values

// Then you need to add some configuration
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"];

// Update the spreadsheet
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

I only want to update specific columns in the row I am editing, how do I skip the ones that I don't want it to touch?

Where I have put "SKIP" I want it to completely ignore that column and keep whatever information is already in it

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve that?

Comment: What code would I write?

Comment: The code to solve your problem :) If you don't want to set specific values, what happens if you just don't set them?

Comment: It rather depends on what values (if any) were already in those cells. If there were existing values, then it would make sense to insert them into the `setValues()` statement. If there weren't existing values, then you could insert a value of '""', perhaps.

Comment: I have this question too! I want to update a row and leave some cells untouched. Using `""` causes the cell to be cleared. Using `null` throws a Google_Service_Exception and results in a 500 error. The documentation says leaving it "empty" will ignore the cell and leaving an "empty string" will clear the cell. But I have no idea how to leave it empty and get the desired result. Worse, leaving two commas in a row results in a PHP error.

Comment: @smts Found this [bug report](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/979) which suggests using `Google_Model::NULL_VALUE` for this. Does it solve the issue? In case it does, then this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025955/write-selectively-to-a-range-in-spreadsheet-not-working-with-null-values-in-php).

Comment: @El_Vanja -- I'll check tonight

Comment: @smts Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, at [the method of spreadsheets.values.append in Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), the values are appended to the next row of the last row in the data range. By this, when you have a sheet including 5 rows and 5 columns of "Sheet1" and you want to put the values to the row 5, even when you use `Sheet1!A5` as the range, the value is put to the row 6. It seems that this is the current specification.

Comment: @smts So, in your situation, how about using [the method of spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)? In this case, you can use `null` as the skip cell and you can use `Sheet1!A5` to above sample situation for putting value. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/979) using `Google_Model::NULL_VALUE` where the column value should be skipped solves the problem.